# strange xdmp.eval() toObject() issue in Marklogic 9

Tags: javascript, marklogic

So I have the following issue, I need to update a array in a JSON document. It is a document that captures project settings, members of the project can read the project document but not update it.

I need to first read the document but is a different transaction, extract the `members` array and go on.

Now the JSON object I get back from the `xdmp.eval()` cannot find the array, the JSON object directly from the `cts.doc()` does ...?

Example project doc at uri '/projects/12345.json':

```
{
"name": "project01",
"description": "example project", 
"id": "12345", 
"members": [
{
"name": "user01", 
"role": "owner", 
"uid": "234"
}, 
{
"name": "user02", 
"role": "member", 
"uid": "123"
}
] 
}
```

My javascript query:

```
var pid = 12345;
// uri to project doc
var pUri = '/projects/' + pid + '.json'

// alternative to not lock project doc
var options = {
             "isolation" : "different-transaction"
              }

//var prjObj = xdmp.eval('cts.doc("' + pUri + '")',null,options).toObject()[0]
//var prjObj = xdmp.eval('cts.doc("' + pUri + '").toObject()',null,options)
var prjObj = cts.doc(pUri).toObject()

prjObj.members
```

gives back the members array as expected but

```
// cast eval result to object
var prjObj = xdmp.eval('cts.doc("' + pUri + '")',null,options).toObject()[0]
// cast doc to object inside eval
var prjObj = xdmp.eval('cts.doc("' + pUri + '").toObject()',null,options);
// end code
```

But returned objects can not find the members array...

now what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`xdmp.eval()` is returning a sequence of 1 `document-node()` objects.

When you invoke `.toObject()` on that sequence, it is converted into an array with one `document-node()`, and then `[0]` is selecting that `document-node()`.

You could then then use `.toObject()` to convert the document node into a JavaScript object:

```
var prjObj = xdmp.eval('cts.doc("' + pUri + '")',null,options).toObject()[0].toObject()
```

Alternatively, you could select the first item from the result sequence using [`fn.head()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/fn.head), and then convert that `document-node()` into a JavaScript object

```
var prjObj = fn.head(xdmp.eval('cts.doc("' + pUri + '")',null,options)).toObject()
```

and then you can use `prjObj.members` to address the members array.